# Sending SMS to multiple numbers from checkbox list

Tags: asp.net

selecting numbers from checkbox list to send sms

how to loop on every number that is been selected

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Selected == true)// getting selected value from CheckBox List  
    {
        str += CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Value + "" + "<br/>"; // add selected Item text to the String .  

        Label1.Text = str;
        //TextBox1.Text = str.ToString();
    }
}
```

send sms to mulitple numbers

Answer (score 0):

Simple, loop the items and add the checked ones to a list.

```
List<string> list = CheckBoxList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(y => y.Value).ToList();
```

Then you can use that list to send sms.